# WorksheetProtection protect(options: WorksheetProtectionOptions) not working in Excel Client in IPad IOS and also in Mac

Tags: office-js

I am trying to use the protect mehtod of Worksheet Protection in Excel client in IOS

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheetprotection.md#protectoptions-worksheetprotectionoption

its works fine if i dont use the option argument in protect method,
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheetprotectionoptions.md#loadparam-object

but i need **allowFormatCells** option to be set to true, with this option its not working correctly in Excel client in IOS IPad, i get error as InValid argument.

This method works fine in Windows environment.

Please let me know how to workaround this.

```
function protectWorksheet() {
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3").format.protection.locked = false;
            //sheet.protection.protect({ allowInsertRows: true });
            sheet.protection.protect({ allowFormatCells: true });
            return ctx.sync();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug -- we are investigating, and will update the thread once we have more info.

Comment: yes, this is a bug, we have raised the ticket to microsoft and they confirmed it that its a bug.

Comment: @shyam_, could you post the exact sample code that is failing for you on the iPad?  We tried a few tests of our own, but they all succeed...

Comment: added code, please check in excel client app (not in browser) in IOS and Mac. 116081114531611 is the case no if you could access.